# Info facebook read_stream permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Java app (still in early development and with only a couple of java classes) I need to access to my wall posts (at the end i'll have to access to my customer wall posts) and list them; in order to do it, i need the read_stream permission
I followed the full instructions of facebook developers site; I submitted my review; the final result was that FB developers denied te read_stream permission; they wrote me this alert:

> **General**
>
> Your app appears to be a test submission. If your app is still
> in development, please wait to submit it for review until it has full
> functionality.
>
> The following items were not reviewed due to general
> issues with your app: read_stream

How can I have the read_stream permission? Any tip is really appreciated

**EDIT START**

I'm using spring-social; in my java code, when I use the method: facebook.feedOperations().getFeed() I access to home posts and I have no problem at all; when I use facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed() I try to access to my wall posts and I got the exception I posted

My Java code:

```
@Override
public PagedList<Post> getPosts() throws Exception
{

    try
    {

        Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(this.facebookClientToken);

        
        if( proxyEnabled )
        {
            if( requestFactory != null )
            {

                ((FacebookTemplate)facebook).setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossibile settare la requestFactory; proxy abilitato ma requestFactory null");
            }
        }
        PagedList<Post> result = facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed();
        result.addAll(facebook.feedOperations().getFeed());
        return result;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String messagge = "Errore nel recupero feed: "+e.getMessage();
        logger.fatal(messagge, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

My StackTrace:

```
09:35:31,939 WARN  [RestTemplate] GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
09:35:31,971 ERROR [CoMiSocialNetworkSvcImpl] Errore nel recupero feed: The operation requires 'read_stream' permission.
org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: The operation requires 'read_stream' permission.
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:116)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:65)
```

regards
Angelo

Comment: Is your app done? If you are just developing you don't send it in for review. You can ask any person that have a role on the app for any permission even if it isn't approved.

Comment: My app is not done; I'm still in early development since my customer asked to me some features I need to check I can realize; in order to check I need to access to my wall posts (in future I'll have to access to my customer wall posts); now if I don't have read_stream permission I can't check if I can realize what my customer asks, and so I'm not sure if I have to realize my app or less

Comment: You can always ask people that have a role on the app.

Comment: I'm the only one in the app; and by doing my tests I'm not able in reading my posts wall

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. In guess is that your app haven't asked you for that permission

Comment: Well honestly I don't know what's wrong; I edited my question by adding the Java code and the stacktrace (partial stacktrace); as you can see I simply try to call my wall posts and I get the error

Comment: Yes so you haven't asked the user for read_steeam permission

Comment: yes this is the point....I asked later and FB team told me what I wrote at the beginning of my question...so what should I do in order to ask the permission and have it?

Comment: Asking Facebook for approval and asking the user for the permission are two completely different things. You just have to ask the user for the permission

Answer (score 1):

If your app needs read_stream permission then you can stop development now - FB will not give you that permission.  Go to the following page to see why:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_posts

(search on "read_stream").

Comment: thank you..i solved my issue by using FB API that opens frame in my web page...thank you again